# How to run multiple S-function modules in one MATLAB/Simulink model？

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function, mpc, mca

The *flag* of the S-function module is a variable defined in the system. The *flag* of one S-function affects the *flag* of another S-function, resulting in a running error. I would like to ask if there is any way to run multiple S-function modules in one MATLAB/Simulink model, as shown in the figure.[Multiple S-function modules in a model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlvOQ.png)

I am trying to run a MATLAB/Simulink model which includes multiple S-function modules.

Comment: I don't think your problem is multiple s-functions, but the fact that one changes the other.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Two s-functions in one Simulink model result in some mess. The flag and state are shared. Have you ever tried to use two s-functions in one model?

Comment: Due to how complation of S-function works, I believe there is only instance of all static memory for all functions. You can try using a DWORK variable to store your flag (https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/about-dwork-vectors.html) to make it instance-specific.